# Any way coercing "list" to S4 "List"?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, r-s4, bioconductor, coercion

Is there any way to coerce simple list-like object to S4 "List" objects? I need to do some vectorization on my data. Apparently, I used nested-lapply on my functions, and I checked its return type as "list". I want "List" like objects. How can I do that? Thanks.

Here is the reproducible example to clarify the issue:

## Data

```
    foo <- GRanges(
      seqnames=Rle(c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr4"), c(3, 2, 1, 2)),
      ranges=IRanges(seq(1, by=9, len=8), seq(7, by=9, len=8)),
      rangeName=letters[seq(1:8)], score=sample(1:20, 8, replace = FALSE))

    bar <- GRanges(
      seqnames=Rle(c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3","chr4"), c(4, 3, 1, 1)),
      ranges=IRanges(seq(2, by=5, len=9), seq(4, by=5, len=9)),
      rangeName=letters[seq(1:9)], score=sample(1:20, 9, replace = FALSE))

    moo <- GRanges(
      seqnames=Rle(c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3","chr4"), c(3, 4, 2,1)),
      ranges=IRanges(seq(5, by=7, len=10), seq(8, by=7, len=10)),
      rangeName=letters[seq(1:10)], score=sample(1:20, 10, replace = FALSE))
```

## Overlap hit-index

```
    grl <- GRangesList(bar, moo)
    res <- lapply(grl, function(ele_) {
        tmp <- as(findOverlaps(foo, ele_), "List")
      })
```

## explanation for duplicated regions (1st list element corresponds to bar):

```
[[1]]
IntegerList of length 8
[[1]] 1 2    # 1st regions from foo overlapped with 1st,2nd regions from bar
[[2]] 3
[[3]] 4
[[4]] 6 7    # 1st regions from foo overlapped with 6st,7th regions from bar
```

## objective only keep one (a.k.a, remove multiple intersected regions), such as:

```
[[1]]
IntegerList of length 8
[[1]] 2   # only keep 2nd region from bar
[[2]] 3
[[3]] 4
[[4]] 6 7 # only keep 6th region from bar
```

## Remove duplicated regions

```
obj.ov <- lapply(res, function(ele_) {
  re <- lapply(grl, function(obj) {
    id0 <- as(which.max(extractList(obj$score, ele_)), "List")
    id0 <- id0[!is.na(id0)]
  })
  re <- re[!duplicated(re)]
})
```

## Further steps

`as.obj.ov <- as(obj.ov, "List")`     # if this coercion is not right, can't be expandable like **obj.ov**

then, **as.obj.ov** must be expandable like **obj.ov** as hit-index vector, also type must be S4 "List" object.

I need let **obj.ov** as **S4 "List"** objects. Is that possible to do such coercion in R ?

Any possible approach, solution, or idea are appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want `class(res)` to be same as `class(grl)`?

Comment: sorry, I updated my post with adding my wanted step to do. class(as.obj.ov) must be S4 "List", and can be expandable like obj.ov as hit-index vector. main reason why I need this coercion is to expand as.obj.ov as GRanges objects by calling extractList methods from S4Vector packages. To expand, I must coerce "list" to S4 "List".

Comment: Can you explain with words what you are trying to achieve? You have 2 ranges (bar, moo), then want to find overlap of those regions with 1 region  (moo), then remove duplicates (btw, I don't understand what do mean by "duplicate".) then we want to use `extractList`, why? Maybe also add expected output?

Comment: I added my explanation on my original post. I want obj.ov as "List", then I can able to expand obj.ov as normal GRanges objects. so far, obj.ov is just hit-index vector, it need to be  S4 "List".

Comment: We can use `findOverlaps(foo, ele_, select = "first")` to keep only first match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `select = "first"` to get first match.

```
lapply(grl, function(ele_) {
  ix <- findOverlaps(foo, ele_, select = "first")
  ele_[ix[!is.na(ix)]]
})

[[1]]
GRanges object with 4 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
      seqnames    ranges strand |   rangeName     score
         <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character> <integer>
  [1]     chr1  [ 2,  4]      * |           a        18
  [2]     chr1  [12, 14]      * |           c         2
  [3]     chr1  [17, 19]      * |           d        19
  [4]     chr2  [27, 29]      * |           f        15
  -------
  seqinfo: 4 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths

[[2]]
GRanges object with 6 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
      seqnames    ranges strand |   rangeName     score
         <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character> <integer>
  [1]     chr1  [ 5,  8]      * |           a        11
  [2]     chr1  [12, 15]      * |           b        13
  [3]     chr1  [19, 22]      * |           c        14
  [4]     chr2  [26, 29]      * |           d        20
  [5]     chr2  [40, 43]      * |           f         8
  [6]     chr4  [68, 71]      * |           j         1
  -------
  seqinfo: 4 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlength
```